# Android back option in action bar

Tags: android

When I created an activity it automatically added a back to main activity option in the action bar. It looks like those are the functions that do it:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
// Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.app_settings, menu);
return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Is there a way to make it go back using finish()? Right now it looks like it resets some values that are saved and I want to keep them. When I tried working with finish() it didn't do it but i'm not sure how to use it in the action bar.

Answer (score 0):

This is simpler and it works perfect:

```
public class BackButtonExample extends Activity {
    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.duahs);

        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#0B4C5F")));
        bar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home:
            this.finish();
            return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
                if(item.getItemId()==android.R.id.home  {
                       finish();
              return true;    }
           else{
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
               }
    }
```